# How can remove current row in JTable when click JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have a number of rows in `JTable` and each row have remove button. I want to delete the current row when I click the remove button of that row. How can I do this?

```
private JButton button;
public MyTableButtonEditor1() {
    button = new JButton("REMOVE");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DbUtility ViewEmployee =new DbUtility();
            ViewEmployee.loadDriver();
            ViewEmployee.connect();
            ResultSet rs= ViewEmployee.executeDeleteQuery(Employeeid);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee Removed");
        }
    });
}
```

Database connection

```
public ResultSet  executeDeleteQuery(String Employeeid ) {

    PreparedStatement pstmt ;
    try {

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM employee  WHERE EmployeeId ="+Employeeid  );


        pstmt.execute();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex){
        // handle any errors
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them - it would be much easier to read :-)

Comment: first: read the example in the tutorial (referenced in the swing tag wiki) on how-to use a button as cellEditor second: apply the learned lesson and ask again (then the answers will make more sense to you)

Answer (score 5):

You have to do it in table model. For instance, if you use `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel` you can call its `removeRow()` method.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE with Feeback from Kleoptra**

Once the button is fired, you need to update the state of the editor and stop the cell editing process.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    deleteFlag = true;

    // This needs to be called that the model and table have a chance to
    // reset themselves...
    stopCellEditing();

}
```

You need to return the `deleteFlag` value from the editors `getCellEditorValue`

```
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return deleteFlag;
}
```

Don't forget to reset your flag when the editor is initialised.

```
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    deleteFlag = false;
    // Set up and return your button...
}
```

Now in your model, you will need to capture the event by overriding the `setValueAt` method of your table model...

```
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
            case indexOfButtonColumn:
                if (aValue instanceof Boolean && ((Boolean) aValue).booleanValue()) {
                    // Delete row from database...
                    // Update you internal model.  DefaultTableModel has a removeRow
                    // method, if you're using it.

                    // Other wise you will need to update your internal model
                    // and fire the rows delete event in order to update the table...
                    fireTableRowsDeleted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
                }
                break;
    }
}
```

Now personally, I would always executing any time consuming tasks in background thread or worker.  This is will prevent the UI from "hanging".

You might like to have read of [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: assuming the button _is-a_ cellEditor and the above is the actionPerformed of that editor - no, simply wrong. But assume you mean it differently :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I'm pretty sure it is a `TableCellEditor` as I helped answer the OP's question about how to set it up...and apart from running within the EDT when he deletes the row...what did I do wrong this time :(

Comment: an editor _must not_ change the model by itself: it's responsibility is to notify the listeners when the edit is terminated, nothing else. It's up to the listener to act on that notification.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for the feedback, it's appriciated, I'm going to go wash my eyes out with bleach and give this some thought...

Comment: @kleopatra never_ending story :-) with JButtons Components as Renderer, Editor and with ActionListener, Swing Action

Comment: @MadProgrammer hard to say whatever cleaver, use only [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) made by his majesty (@camickr)

Comment: looks okay now, assuming you return the deleteFlag as editorValue :-)

Comment: @mKorbel on a cursory look, it seems like Rob's editor ... isn't a strictly valid implementation (if the delegate action changes the model)

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for reminding me to return the `deleteFlag`, was in my test code, didn't make it to the post

Comment: @mKorbel The OP was suggested to look at the Table Button Column, but no, I didn't base any of my suggestions on it, but I agree, it would have been easier :P (ps Thanks every body, I do appreciate the feedback)

Comment: @kleopatra I remember a few your code examples, last from yesterday or two - three days back, agree with Model_to_View, but you are very active and best leader for CompoundComponents here, then rest of readers can ignored your comment, without link (last post about) or answer here, 1) I voting to transfering your comments as a answwer here, 2) please :-), 3) code, explanations that haven't got any issue with empty AbstractTableModel based on any of possible ZOO_Arrays

Comment: @mKorbel sorry, don't know what you mean (and too lazy to try deciphering your comment ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of errors in your posted code - no `actionPerformed` for 
jButton1 and no import for `ListSelectionModel`.

It looks like you are using NetBeans?? You can set the list selection model 
as a property of the table at design time. As the IDE should also have 
created the `actionPerformed` event (as guarded code) I am not sure where that 
has gone.

```
model.removeRow(rowid); // this line is all you need 
//table.remove(rowid); <- this line is probably the error
```

Removing from the model is sufficient - you don't need to do a remove from 
the table component. I think this remove is inherited from 
`java.awt.Component` and is trying to remove a component from the table.