# Removing Row from DefaultTableModel Object

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

Recently I've been encountered a weird problem. Whenever I try to remove row in TableModelListener which belongs to DefaultTableModel object, I am getting ArrayOutOfBounds Exception 0>=0, 1>=1(depends on what I choose) I've found similar problem here:

[java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0 attempting to populate JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732503/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-0-0-attempting-to-populate-jtable)

However, still couldnt fix it. My purpose is when the user select delete option in the combobox, I simply want to remove that row entirely. removeRow()method works properly outside of listeners by the way. Here is the code and explanation:

```
String[] columnNames = {"Kargo ID",
                "Alıcı Adres",
                "Ağırlık(KG)",
                "Tutar(TL)",
                "Alım Saati","Durum","İletim Saati"};

        Object[][] data = {
                {new Integer(3), "Sinan Caddesi",
                    new Integer(100), new Integer(5),"" ,"",""}};



        final DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
        final JTable table = new JTable(dtm){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return column == 5;//Combobox column
            }

        };

        //Making Combobox
        TableColumn c = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5);
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem("");
        comboBox.addItem("Delete");

        c.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

        //System.out.println(dtm.getRowCount());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(false);

        //I printed row and column numbers, they re correct. 
        dtm.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                int row = e.getFirstRow();
                int column = e.getColumn();
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)e.getSource();
                Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);
                //System.out.println(data); DATA IS CORRECT
                if(((String)data).equals("Delete"))
                    dtm.removeRow(row);//Exception Here

                //System.out.println(row + " " + column);
            }
        });
```

Am I missing some important point? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using the `TableModelListener` is not an appropriate means by which to modify the table model, because the table model will fire another table changed event when you modify it so on and so forth...Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795442/how-can-remove-current-row-in-jtable-when-click-jbutton/12795907#12795907) for better ideas

Comment: Then how to listen data changes in the table? I already tried to add actionListener to combobox instead of table but the result was same.

Comment: Listening for changes and making modifications based on those changes are two different things.  Take a look at the linked example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "very" basic idea is, when `TableModel#setValue` is called, you want to check the `column` that was modified.  If the `column` is (in this case) `5`, you'll want to check what the value is...

For example...

```
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex == 5) {
        if ("Delete".equals(aValue)) {
            removeRow(rowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Remember, the above example overrides the default behaviour of `setValueAt`, so if you're relying on the values to updated in the model, you need to call `super.setValueAt(...)`

Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: I really dont know what to say. Really, really thank you so much. I just created inner class which extends to DefaultTableModel, overrided a setValueMethod and defined new object from my inner class instead of directly from Dtm class. And the job is done. Have a nice day ! ^_^