# remove a row from jtable with jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with JButton like this.
[first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oIOV.png)

if I click the "+" button,the table is like this.
[second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfWuC.jpg)

then, if I click the "-" button on the second line, it's ok.

now the table has only one row which was added by the "+" button.

so the question is that, I clicked the "-" button on the row,it throws an exception below:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:664)
```

what happened？

this is my code:

```
public class TableDeleteButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JButton button;
String label;
boolean isPushed;
Vector<Vector<String>> vPartsTypeData;

DefaultTableModel dtm;
JTable partsTypeValueTable;

public TableDeleteButtonEditor(Vector<Vector<String>> vPartsTypeData, DefaultTableModel dtm, JTable partsTypeValueTable) {

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    //this.setClickCountToStart(1);
    this.vPartsTypeData = vPartsTypeData;
    this.dtm = dtm;
    this.partsTypeValueTable = partsTypeValueTable;
    this.vPartsTypeData = vPartsTypeData;
    button = new JButton();
    int selectedRow = partsTypeValueTable.getSelectedRow();
    System.out.println("selectedRow:"+selectedRow);
    System.out.println("Count:"+vPartsTypeData.size());
    button.addActionListener(new deleteButtonListener());
}

public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(final JTable table, Object value,  boolean isSelected,int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
        button.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,30));
        button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());  
        button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());  
    } else {
        button.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,30));
        button.setForeground(table.getForeground());  
        button.setBackground(table.getBackground());  
    }  
    label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();  
    button.setText(label);
    isPushed = true;  
    return button;  
}  

public Object getCellEditorValue() {  
    if (isPushed) {

    }  
    isPushed = false;  
    return new String(label);  
}  

public boolean stopCellEditing() {  
    isPushed = false;
    return super.stopCellEditing();  
}  

public class deleteButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("-----");
        int selectedRow = partsTypeValueTable.getSelectedRow();
        //System.out.println("selectedRow:"+selectedRow);
        //System.out.println("Count:"+vPartsTypeData.size());
        dtm.removeRow(selectedRow-1);

        //vPartsTypeData.remove(partsTypeValueTable.getSelectedRow());
        System.out.println("tableCount:"+partsTypeValueTable.getRowCount());
        //dtm.fireTableChanged(null);
        partsTypeValueTable.setModel(dtm);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                partsTypeValueTable.repaint();
                partsTypeValueTable.validate();
                partsTypeValueTable.updateUI();
                dtm.fireTableDataChanged();
            }
            });

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Everything in `invokeLater` is useless. `partsTypeValueTable.setModel(dtm);` is also a bad idea. Basically your `TableCellEditor` is taking on to much responsibility

Comment: [This is possibly a better approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795442/how-can-remove-current-row-in-jtable-when-click-jbutton/12795907#12795907), but, personally, I don't like "buttons" in `JTable`s and prefer to do something more like [this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070511/add-jbutton-to-each-row-of-a-jtable/25071138#25071138)

Comment: if I remove invokelater，updateUI will throws an nullpoint exception.I don't know why.

Comment: Understand what `updateUI` actually does, it's not doing what you think.  Also, the `TableModel` is responsible for generating mutation events when they occur, which will trigger an update the `JTable` (as it's listening to the model). There's no reason why the editor should be interacting with the model directly like this - that's my opinion, but that's not it's overall responsibility

Comment: So, "possible" problem - When the `ActionListener` is triggered, it is changing the state of the `TableModel`, which is causing the editor to be dismissed (stopped) which triggers a call to the `TableModel`'s `setValueAt` method ... but guess which row no longer exists ... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a little bit of a look at the stack trace can lead us to a better understanding of what's going on...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:664)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2741)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4723)
    at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(AbstractCellEditor.java:141)
    at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.stopCellEditing(AbstractCellEditor.java:85)
```

So, basically `stopCellEditing` is triggering a call to `setValueAt`, passing in the editing `row`, `column` and the result of `getCellEditorValue`, but, since this occurs AFTER the `ActionListener` has removed the row from the `TableModel`, it breaks, as the row, which `setValueAt` is trying to update simply no longer exists (or worse is a different row altogether).

It's not the responsibility of the `TableCellEditor` to modify the `TableModel`, instead, it should be reporting back to the `TableModel` a state value which it can use to make decisions about what it should do.

A simplified version of the editor might look something like...

```
public class TableDeleteButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JButton button;
    boolean isPushed;

    public TableDeleteButtonEditor() {
        button = new JButton();
        button.addActionListener(new DeleteButtonListener());
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(final JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            button.setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        button.setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        isPushed = false;
        return button;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return isPushed;
    }

    public class DeleteButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            isPushed = true;
            stopCellEditing();
        }
    }
}
```

The core functionality of the editor simply revolves around the state of the `isPushed` value.

The `TableModel` now needs to inspect this value when `setValueAt` is called and respond to it

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
    if (column == 0 && (aValue instanceof Boolean)) {
        boolean pushed = (boolean) aValue;
        if (pushed) {
            removeRow(row);
        }
    }
}
```

And viola, row is now deleted and everybody is happy.

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"A"}, 0) {
                    @Override
                    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
                        if (column == 0 && (aValue instanceof Boolean)) {
                            boolean pushed = (boolean) aValue;
                            if (pushed) {
                                removeRow(row);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                model.addRow(new Object[]{"-"});
                model.addRow(new Object[]{"-"});
                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
                column.setCellEditor(new TableDeleteButtonEditor());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TableDeleteButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

        /**
         *
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        JButton button;
        boolean isPushed;
        JTable partsTypeValueTable;

        public TableDeleteButtonEditor() {
            button = new JButton();
            button.addActionListener(new DeleteButtonListener());
        }

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(final JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            partsTypeValueTable = table;
            if (isSelected) {
                button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
                button.setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
            button.setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
            isPushed = false;
            return button;
        }

        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return isPushed;
        }

        public class DeleteButtonListener implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                isPushed = true;
                stopCellEditing();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, I don't like this approach, it's a personally thing, but as a user, I find it frustrating and much prefer something more [like this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070511/add-jbutton-to-each-row-of-a-jtable/25071138#25071138).

However, you might like to also have a look at [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for another approach

Comment: thank you for your help! I was bothered by the question for 3 days.

Comment: Welcome to the forest, watch out for the trees ;)